# Grep find files that don't contain string and then use sed to prepend multi line string to files

Tags: macos, sed, terminal, grep

I'm looking to do 2 things to a group of text files in a folder but haven't been able to do so:

1. Find and exclude text files in a folder containing the string `Title:`
2. Add the Multi line string **below** to the results.

> Title:
>   Author:
>   Type:
>   Genre:
>   Format:

I can do the first step doing this:

```
find . -type f | grep -L  "Title: "
```

For the second step I'm using this command but it is unable to work with multiple lines.

```
find . -type f | grep -L  "Title: " * | sed -i '1iTitle:\Author:\Type:\Genre:\Format:\'
```

But I'm unable to get it to work.

Comment: when you exclude files that contain `Title:`, do you want to only check first line or anywhere in the file? if it is only first line, solution would be lot simpler

Comment: I only want to check the first line.

Comment: try `find -type f -exec sed -i '1 {/Title:/! s/.*/Title:\nAuthor:\nType:\nGenre:\nFormat:\n&/}' {} +` inside the directory... or just `sed -i '1 {/Title:/! s/.*/Title:\nAuthor:\nType:\nGenre:\nFormat:\n&/}' *` if you have only files in that directory

Answer (score 0):

what about recursive grep to avoid `find` then call `sed` on the result? (note that your `sed` expression cannot work; using a sedfile you can do what you want)

```
grep -rL "Title: " | xargs sed -i -f sedfile
```

`sedfile` being as below

```
1i\
Title:\
Author:\
Type:\
Genre:\
Format:
```

(BTW check that the `sed` version you're using has the `-i` option as "in-place", I'm not sure of that. In that case it will be a little more complex, but still doable)